# React iFrame displaying oddly in IE11 - Bootstrap classes not working

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

I have a React app that is showing an iFrame that is supposed to have a menu styled via Bootstrap (v.3.2, because reasons unfortunately) . And it works fine except for IE11 where I can see that the bootstrap classes are not being applied. I have checked and saw that I need to make sure to include

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11">`

but that does not seem to make a difference.

Unfortunately a lot of posts about IE are from years ago since it is not being actively supported any more so I am a little out of luck.

**EDIT**

Also, not sure if it is relevant but as far as using F12/inspector tools when I try to inspect it in the DOM explorer it just shows the  tag of the iFrame but it does not show any of the contents of the iFrame like it does in the Chrome browser.

Also I was wondering if it is possible that Bootstrap and jQuery is not being loaded properly because it is the iFrame that is including them instead of the React app itself?

**EDIT 2**

I think I figured it out. Despite all the surrounding divs and classes being named "iframe-" etc now that I have the code I saw that they were actually using an `<object>` and then tying the data to that. When I replaced it with an ACTUAL `<iframe>` it appears as expected. I still need to rule out that it is not just working because I did something after the DOM was fully renderd (though I did double check and adding another `<object>` with the same source after the app mounted did not work) but am I getting more and more confident that is the root of the problem.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could also try to use F12 developer tools to check whether the bootstrap reference is load success and the html elements CSS styles.

Comment: I do not have access to the code yet but I can later. As far as using F12 when I try to inspect it in the DOM explorer it just shows the <object> tag of the iFrame but it does not show any of the contents of the iFrame like it does in the Chrome browser.

Comment: When using F12 developer tools to debug the code, try to use [the Network tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v=vs.85)) to check whether the JQuery and Bootstrap reference load success and the iframe content page load success. Besides, please use the [Console tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255006(v=vs.85)) to check whether there has some error?